# service.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe") doesn't return files shared by my Android App

Tags: google-drive-api

I have successfully uploaded a file to Drive and inserted permissions of another account to share.  All this is working.  But when I try from the other account to list out the shared files for download, it returns that there are no files.

Does anyone know how to retreive files that are shared from another user?

Here is what I've tried.

```
private class RetrieveAllShareFiles extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    Files.List request = null;
    try {
        request = service.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    do {
        try {
            FileList files = request.execute();
            filesResult.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
        request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
    return "Executed";
    }
```

Comment: What OAuth scope are you using? Can you see the shared files in the Drive UI of the other user?

Comment: Using:
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);

Yes, with the Google Drive UI, I can see the shared files.

When I try this:
    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);

On the files.list() request, I get the following exception:
Cause= UserRecoverableAuthException
detailMessage= "NeedPermission"

Answer (score 1):

When using the `drive.files` scope your app will only be able to access files that you have created with it or that the user is opening from the Drive UI.
When the file is shared with another user, he won't be able to see it using the drive.files scope. For this use case you should request access to the full Drive scope.

Check the documentation for more details on the available OAuth scopes: https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes